# Android Studio import module from source - Cannot specify module name

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, module

I am attempting to create an Android Java App using OpenCV. I use Android Studio 4.0.

After creating a new "empty activity" project, I attempt to import the OpenCV Android SDK by `File -> New -> Import Module...`. I select the `/sdk/java` folder of the OpenCV Android SDK distribution. The import of the module appears to work. However, the imported module I'm ending up with has the name `java`. I looked through various documentation & tutorials and it seems that the `Import Module from Source` dialog should provide a `Module Name` field which allows me to specify the module's name such as `"opencv-4.3.0"`.
However, I don't have such a field in the dialog:
[image]

For reference, here's a screenshot from an [OpenCV forum answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/222392/importing-opencv-4x-android-sdk-module-into-android-studio/):
[image]

I tried this both with Android Studio 4.0 and 4.1 beta 3 both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu.
What am I missing?